# Cant deposit to aave from a smart contract

Tags: solidity

I have deployed with contract to kovan. When I try to call it from my browser using scaffold-eth I get the error "The execution failed due to an exception.", data: "Reverted" ".
Why is this call failing?

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

import "hardhat/console.sol";

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@aave/protocol-v2/contracts/interfaces/ILendingPoolAddressesProvider.sol";
import "@aave/protocol-v2/contracts/interfaces/ILendingPool.sol";


contract YourContract {

  constructor() public {
    // what should we do on deploy?
  }

    function depositToAave() public {
        
        // Retrieve LendingPool address
        ILendingPoolAddressesProvider provider = ILendingPoolAddressesProvider(address(0x88757f2f99175387aB4C6a4b3067c77A695b0349)); // mainnet address, for other addresses: https://docs.aave.com/developers/developing-on-aave/deployed-contract-instances
        ILendingPool lendingPool = ILendingPool(provider.getLendingPool());

        
        // // Input variables
        address daiAddress = address(0x4F96Fe3b7A6Cf9725f59d353F723c1bDb64CA6Aa); // kovan DAI
        uint256 amount = 1;
        uint16 referral = 0;

        
        // // Approve LendingPool contract to move your DAI
        IERC20(daiAddress).approve(provider.getLendingPool(), amount);
        
        // Deposit 1 DAI
        lendingPool.deposit(daiAddress, amount, address(msg.sender), referral);
        //lendingPool.getReservesList();

  }

  
}
```